# Solving Biharmonic type Fourth Order PDE in Two-dimensional Polar Coordinates.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am completely lost on solving the following Fourth order Partial Differential Equation involving fourth Power of Del Operator. I am weak in solving PDE in general and this totally gives me a headache. I found in internet that this is of biharmonic type (!!!)

\begin{equation}
\nabla^4w + (\frac{NC^2}{D})\nabla^2w = 0,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2= \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial }{\partial r} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2} ,
\end{equation}

$N,C$ and $D$ are some constants.

Is there a method to solve this?

Comment: What is the domain for the problem, and what boundary conditions are you imposing?

Comment: Try using separation of variables

Comment: How ? Can you elaborate?